# General Method to arrange $n^n$, $(n-1)^{(n-1)}$, $(n+1)^{(n+1)}$, $(n-1)^{(n+1)}$, $(n+1)^{(n-1)}$ in ascending order.

Tags: inequality

Is there a general method to arrange $n^n$, $(n-1)^{(n-1)}$,  $(n+1)^{(n+1)}$,  $(n-1)^{(n+1)}$, $(n+1)^{(n-1)}$ in ascending order?

I am interested **in a general method which works for all real values of n.**

*Highly original and intuitive methods which may work for specific cases of n also appreciated.*

*I would also like to understand some beautiful and thought provoking methods(such as proof without words)*

Eventually,

My last question is whether we can arrange

$n^n$, $(n-k)^{(n-k)}$,  $(n+k)^{(n+k)}$,  $(n-k)^{(n+k)}$, $(n+k)^{(n-k)}$ in ascending order.

Where $k$ is a *arbitrary positive constant*.

**Caution** : *Consider only those values for the above expressions are **defined** and **real**.*

Comment: General Approaches to consider.

Comment: 1. Induction 2. Calculus(maybe) 3.Graphical 4. Using some identity?

Comment: For many real values of $n$, the indicated quantities are not defined. Perhaps you'd be happy with, e.g., $n > 1$?

Comment: @Travis Yes I edited the question to make it more clear. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: for what stands $k$ here?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Thanks, I defined $k$ as you had asked me to do.

Answer (score 1):

*(Note that the question moved on while I was thinking and typing... I leave this here anyway for interest)*

Provided all the quantities are greater than $e$, you have that for $a>b, a^b<b^a$. We can relate this to the value of $f(x)=\frac{\large \log x}{\large x}$ since: 
$a^b<b^a \implies b\log a <a\log b \implies \frac{\large \log a}{\large a} <\frac{\large \log b}{\large b}$
and given that $f(x)$ is monotonic decreasing for $x>e$, it is clear that  $a^b<b^a \implies a>b$ if both are in this range.

The remaining uncertainty is ordering $n^n$ and $(n-k)^{n+k}$ (and I read $k$ as a small offset on $n$, rather than an unconstrained value). $k$ has to be a significant proportion of $n$, in general, to undermine $(n-k)^{n+k}>n^n$. For example (in the integers) for $n=23$ you only need $k<17$ to keep $(n-k)^{n+k}>n^n$ .

So least for $n\ge5$, the initial asked ordering is
 $$(n-1)^{(n-1)}<(n+1)^{(n-1)}<n^n<(n-1)^{(n+1)}<(n+1)^{(n+1)}
$$

---

($5$ is the minimum value in the integers for this ordering, but the actual crossover in the reals is extremely close to $n=\pi+1$, above which point $n^n<(n-1)^{(n+1)}$ is true. This threshold value is from (spreadsheet) calculation, not any theoretical assessment).

Comment: I actually did not get what you are trying to say.

Comment: Can you edit your answer especially the last part to explain it a little more clearly?

Comment: Ah, you're right, of course!

Comment: @Travis Can you clarify? What is right?

Comment: @PrashantGokhale I was responding to Joffan.

Comment: @Travis Oh Sorry!